# Order of Riemann tensor indexes and the Ricci Identity

Tags: differential-geometry, notation, riemannian-geometry, tensors, curvature

I have seen the Ricci identity written variously as

1. $R_{ijk}{}^l x^k = (\nabla_i\nabla_j- \nabla_j\nabla_i) x^l$
2. $R_{ij}{}^l{}_k x^k = (\nabla_i\nabla_j- \nabla_j\nabla_i) x^l$
3. $R^l{}_{kij} x^k = (\nabla_i\nabla_j- \nabla_j\nabla_i) x^l$

To my understanding 2. and 3. are equivalent but 1. has the opposite sign
due to the symmetries of the Riemann tensor.
Oddly I do not recall ever seeing the 4 possible variant.

Which is the correct form?

Comment: At most, the difference would be a minus sign that could be absorbed into the formulas that use the Riemann tensor. I do not think this question can be answered until you state some formulas or theorems that the convention should be consistent with.

Comment: @Muphrid I know either convention can be used consistently, but you can get burned if you are working with calculations from different sources that use opposite conventions. I just lost a ton of time tracing a problem in my calculations due to this. I was doing some work using the xAct Mathematica package. xAct uses 2. but I was entering my equations assuming 1. since that is how I learned tensors. It never occurred to me that opposite conventio was also in use and I could not figure out why my paper calculations did not agree with the computer results.